# Tri folded online brochure as website, how do I animate?

Tags: jquery, jquery-animate, flip, fold

I'm currently checking the web for solutions to my next problem. I want to create an online e-brochure for a company that makes printed matter of different kinds.

The brochure, or folder, or whatever you really call it, should be devided into three pieces. A tri-fold.

And I want it to animate with javascript I think. I'm not really into flash.

It should look like this example: (http://flyingtinman.com/PV3D/cards/trifold.swf) with options to click and open/close different sides in both horizontal directions, aswell as flipping everything to it's back.

This should be possible with jQuery or something similar. The most effecient way would be if there already was a library (that I can't find).

Anyone know any tutorial or something like that?

Answer (score 0):

For page flip simulation in JavaScript you will need to animate in either Canvas or WebGL. Tutorials for this. None that I know of or API's that allow mesh bending. This stuff is still a bit new, flash is still going to be better than canvas animations, smoother for all browsers etc. WebGL is the only competitor for flash. But that's IE 10 supposedly.